# Add multiple tables and files as input for Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm looking for a way to setup multiple tables and files as inputs for hadoop job.

To setup multiple tables as inputs we can use this API

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(scans, MyMapper.class, Text.class, Text.class, job);
```

To add file inputs to job we can use this API

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path, TextInputFormat.class, myMapper);
```

However, combination of them does not work. It seems that first method works exclusively. I know a method to add **1** hbase table and files as input:

```
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, new String(tableName));
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, convertScanToString(scan));
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("HT_" + new String(tableName)), TableInputFormat.class, myMapper);
// here we can file inputs as before
```

It works only for **1** table input, because input table name and scan are set to config exclusively. Can we do something to support multiple tables and files?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can try to use a MultiTableInputFormat instead TableInputFormat, it has parameter MultiTableInputFormat.SCANS. Table name for scan set as scan parameter `scan.attributes.table.name`. E.g.

```
scan1.setAttribute(`scan.attributes.table.name`, tableName1)
scan2.setAttribute(`scan.attributes.table.name`, tableName2)
conf.setStrings(MultiTableInputFormat.SCANS,
                 convertScanToString(scan1),
                 convertScanToString(scan2));
MultiTableInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("HT_" + new String(tableName)), MultiTableInputFormat.class, myMapper);
```